# Keeping the GIMP tool bar on top?

Tags: graphics

I've seen a lot of discussion about this through googling, but found no answers. In GIMP for Mac, I just want to keep all the dialog windows above my main document window. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you need all the features of GIMP? If not, [Seashore](http://seashore.sourceforge.net/) is a GIMP fork with a Cocoa interface. Not as feature-rich but the UI is much more Mac-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the SIMBL extension, [afloat](http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/). I use this tool all the time, especially when working with reference images and the like.